# Use Jquery :visible in an if ( x && y ) statement OR how do I stop mid-animation input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

http://rockforddriveline.com/newrdl/index.html

That is the test website. Its a WIP, don't discuss the design. Just the functionality.

So, I've edited my post, and I've changed my code to the bare minimum to the point to where it *works*. My issue is that during the transition between the .tile and main, it hides both of them which then displays nothing. I want to be able to make sure that doesn't happen. I have two methods I think that'll solve it. Either by stopping input of the mouse during the animation or use a listener to see when both .m1/2/3/4 and .t1/2/3/4 are :hidden. I don't know how to do either of those.

**.stop() did not solve my problem.**

```
var varMainHide = '.m1, .m2, .m3, .m4',
    varTileHide = '.t1, .t2, .t3, .t4',
    varAllHide = varMainHide + ', ' + varMainHide;

function funcSimpleTransition(fMain, button){

    $(button).click(function() {
            $(varMainHide).hide();
            $('.tile').hide(500);
            $(fMain).show(300);         
    });
    $('.overide').click(function() {
        $(varMainHide).hide(200);
        $('.tile').show();
    });
};

function funcMasterScript(){
    $(varMainHide).hide();
    funcSimpleTransition('.m1', '.t1');
    funcSimpleTransition('.m2', '.t2');
    funcSimpleTransition('.m3', '.t3');
    funcSimpleTransition('.m4', '.t4');
};
```

Comment: You did not read my post very well. Let me TL;DR that for you: .stop() would cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Maybe you need to use [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to solve the problem? That would cause the show/hide events to run sequentially rather than all at the same time.

Comment: I thought about it, but unfortunately then it would make the transitions look strange.

Comment: Possibly, but if, by your own admission, it's for an edge case scenario anyway, for that small number of people, would you rather have it look "strange" or be broken? :)

Comment: I'd rather have that small little glitch than have it look weird. To be perfectly honest, no one will ever find a bug like this unless they actually _try_ to break my code. More or less, this for my sound of mind. ;)

Comment: I have adjusted the text of my question so it is a little bit easier to understand as well as simplified my code.